# Why did smarty registerPlugin() stop workgin somewhere around v3.1.30?

Tags: php, smarty-plugins

I migrated from smarty `v3.1.29` to `v3.1.33` and my registered plugins stopped working. Why?

I used this syntax:

```
$this -> registerPlugin ( "function", "tpl_func", "php_func" );
```

The behaviour goes wrong only with `php 7.0`. With `php 7.3.14` it still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not where you call the function but where you define it.

In older versions of smarty the following syntax did work:

```
function php_func($params, &$smarty) {
    return "blah";
}
```

In the newer versions this is incorrect. You should use this one (remove the `&` from the second argument):

```
function php_func($params, $smarty) {
    return "blah";
}
```

The same holds for smarty `block`s and smarty `function`s as well.